# adjustResize doesn't work when I add a scroll view in my layout

Tags: android, layout, keyboard

I have this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.b2875.Messaggi$PlaceholderFragment" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="650dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ScriviMessaggio"
        android:layout_width="332dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/scriviMessaggio" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/invia"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/invia" />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearVertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/AreaMessaggi"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/messaggi" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I click my editText my keyboard cover the editText the button and part of scrollview.. 
Then I added to my activity in the manifest this:

```
<activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:name="com.example.b2875.Messaggi"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

I have seen that this was helpful for other people but not for me, there is no difference if I put the `windowSoftInputMode = "adjustResize"` or not. The result is everytime the same:my keyboard cover half of layout.. 
What can be the solution??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` this in manifest file to

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

Comment: Nothing to do.. the same result

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
  <RelativeLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      tools:context="com.example.b2875.Messaggi$PlaceholderFragment" >


<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:layout_marginTop="650dp" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ScriviMessaggio"
    android:layout_width="332dp"
    android:layout_height="71dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/scriviMessaggio" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/invia"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/invia" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearVertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AreaMessaggi"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/messaggi" />
   </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

   </ScrollView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"` in manifest as well in `Activity` tag.